# Python - inherit a method from a class but with a different name

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have to define a class (call it `ABC`) that inherits from another class (call it `SuperABC`). The class I am inheriting from (`SuperABC`) has a method (lets call it `func`) that I need to use. But the problem is that I have to define a method with same name (i.e `func`) in class `ABC` which calls the `func` method of the `SuperABC` class and does additional things. I realized I could solve this issue if I can inherit the `func` method from `SuperABC` but with a different alias. Is it possible to do so?

Currently I have just copied the `func` method from `SuperABC` class, added it to the `ABC` class and changed its name to `_func`. Is there any other way to do this?

Lastly, I looked into the usage of `super`. But from what I have read, it looks like `super` can resolve the current question if I am inheriting that method only from one class. What if I was inheriting from `SuperABC` and `BatABC` and wanted to use of both of theirs `func` method in the `func` method of the `ABC` class by changing names or any other method? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What's wrong with calling `SuperABC.func()` inside `ABC.func()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean something like this:

```
class ABC(SuperABC):
    def _func(*args, **kwargs):
        return SuperABC.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

And if you want to get rid of the actual inheritance of the original `func` add:

```
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        return
```

Another way to do that 2nd step would be to change the `func` during the `__init__` stage, but then you might overwrite something else in there if it's not done carefully.

If you want to inherit 2 `func` from 2 different classes (and `func` is the same name in both), you would have to define an intermediary class that changes the name of one of them first

Answer (score 0):

Just forward the call.

```
 def _func(*args, **kwargs):
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `_func = func` would be simpler and a lot more efficient (since it avoids constructing and calling an additional function).

Answer (score 0):

If you *need* to do it this particular way:

```
subclass_function_name = super().parentfunctionname
```

If you're using Python 2, you need to add the args in super(). Note this is **NOT** a call to the parentfunctionname but a reference to the function object.